# Copying new file while retaining the original file

Tags: copy

How to create new file with the new name from the existing file in the same directory? The following command doesnt work since it removes the original file `server.properties`.

```
$ mv server.properties server-0.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy a file, you can use the `cp` (for "copy") command

```
cp /path/to/sourceFile path/to/newFile
```

in your case it will be

```
cp server.properties server-0.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use copy (cp) rather than move (mv).

```
cp server.properties server-0.properties
```

More here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/cp.1.html